# use array in bash for change name of created folder in each loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a script in bash and the idea is that I have an array with text and I use to creat a folder, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=(dir1 dir2 dir3)
for i in 0 1 2; do
    d=run_${#dir[i]}
    echo "Prepare case ${d}..."
done
```

My problem is that when I do this, it prints:

```
Prepare case run_4...
Prepare case run_4...
Prepare case run_4...
```

and the number 4 corresponds to the lenght of each array element, (if I change dir1 to direc1 for example, I get in the first line of the output "Prepare case run_6...")

What i was looking:

```
Prepare case run_dir1...
Prepare case run_dir2...
Prepare case run_dir3...
```

What i am missing?

Comment: Then why did you use `${#`? What do you think `#` means?

Comment: [Bookmark this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: why not just use your `$i` directly, or at least `d=run_${i}`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#` from this commnd `d=run_${#dir[i]}`

And you can loop over array values like this:

```
for i in "${dir[@]}"; do
    echo "Prepare case run_$i..."
done
```